# Generating named tuples of arrays on a map of a function that produces named tuples

Tags: julia, namedtuple

Take for example a function that generates named tuples

```
f(t) = (a=t,b=2t)
```

I can easily create an array of named tuples

```
ts = 0.0:0.01:1.0
X = f.(ts)
```

But instead, I want the similar struct of arrays format:

```
Y = (a=collect(ts),b=collect(2ts))
```

How do you efficiently generate this? I am quite close. If I know the names ahead of time, I can write it out like:

```
Y = (a=Vector{Float64}(undef,length(t)),b=Vector{Float64}(undef,length(t)))
for (i,t) in enumerate(ts)
  val = f(t)
  for (j,x) in enumerate(Y)
    Y[j][i] = val[j]
  end
end
Y
```

However, generating that `Y` with the right names is the issue. I can get the names like

```
template = f(first(ts))
syms = fieldnames(typeof(template))
```

but does how is that `Y` generated from knowing those names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about directly construct `Y` using the NamedTuple{N, T} constructor?

```
julia> f(t) = (a=t,b=2t)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> ts = 0.0:0.01:1.0
0.0:0.01:1.0

julia> X = f.(ts);

julia> p(template::NamedTuple{N}, value::T) where {N, T} = NamedTuple{N, T}(value)
p (generic function with 1 method)

julia> p(X[1], (rand(4), rand(4)))
(a = [0.879929, 0.985692, 0.815627, 0.379551], b = [0.289546, 0.687192, 0.228028, 0.545847])

julia> typeof(ans)
NamedTuple{(:a, :b),Tuple{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}}}
```

Comment: This is a fantastic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Kristoffer Carlsson showed me that [StructArrays.jl](https://github.com/piever/StructArrays.jl) provides a good answer if the reason for getting a named tuple of arrays is to build a DataFrame or JuliaDB table. Using his hints I came up with:

```
template = f(first(ts))
Y = [Vector{Float64}(undef,length(ts)) for i in 1:length(template)]
for (i,t) in enumerate(ts)
  val = f(t)
  for (j,x) in enumerate(Y)
    Y[j][i] = val[j]
  end
end
_Y = StructArray{typeof(template)}(Y...)

using DataFrames
@time DataFrame(_Y)
```

Comment: So is this question about auto-converting Type to Symbol when the type is an type of array?

Comment: No, it's about doing a array of structs to struct of array conversion.

Comment: so if the column name does not matter, what would  df1 = DataFrame(vcat([y for y in Y])) do?

Comment: The column names matter.

Comment: Still, creating the dataframe from the parts of Y directly within a DataFrame constructor and then renaming the columns in the DataFrame with names!(df,...) seems more straightforward.

Comment: In a few months I'll want to make this JuliaDB where the column names aren't mutable (AFICT), and I was hoping to directly create their underlying data formats to make it easy to make the choice without extra operations.

Comment: Ah, yes, best not to have an extra dependency on DataFrames then :).